# create php function for different queries

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a query which I need to run multiple times within a page with different varriables I would need help with creating a function which would do the same as this code:

```
    $type = "A";
    $getRecordsQuery = "SELECT * from records where domain_id=$domainID and type='". $type ."'" or die("Error:" . \mysqli_error($link));
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $getRecordsQuery);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
die("Error: " . mysqli_error($link));
    } else {
        echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>IP</td>
                <td>DynDNS</td>
                <td>TTL</td>
            </tr>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $name = $row["name"];
                $ip = $row["content"];
                $ttl = $row["ttl"];
                echo "<tr>
                    <td>". $name ."</td>
                    <td>". $ip ."</td>
                    <td>Off</td>
                    <td>". $ttl ."<td>
                </tr>";
            }
    echo "</table>";
```

Basically this queries a table from the database and it puts the required information in a table. I would need the function to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using MYSQLI_* so lookup prepare() and execute(). Then prepare it once and pass paramters to it 10000 times and execute unique quesries 1000 times if you like. {RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically put the code in a function block that you can call -

```
function getData($domainID, $domainType, $link) {
    $getRecordsQuery = "SELECT * from records where domain_id=$domainID and type='". $domainType ."'" or die("Error:" . \mysqli_error($link));
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $getRecordsQuery);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error($link));
    } else {
        $table = "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>IP</td>
                <td>DynDNS</td>
                <td>TTL</td>
            </tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $name = $row["name"];
            $ip = $row["content"];
            $ttl = $row["ttl"];
            $table .= "<tr>
                          <td>". $name ."</td>
                          <td>". $ip ."</td>
                          <td>Off</td>
                          <td>". $ttl ."<td>
                      </tr>";
        }
    $table .= "</table>";
    return $table;
}
```

Then you can call it while passing in the domain id and type.

```
echo getData($fooID, $barType, $databaseConnection);
```

You also have to pass in the database connection as you have likely made that connection somewhere outside of this function.

This can be greatly improved by learning about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and using them to help prevent problems like [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: `prepare()` and `execute()` You can lead a horse to water but you cannot make it drink

Comment: That's why I included the info @RiggsFolly. I wasn't planning to rewrite all of the code for the OP. Thanks for the DV :)

Comment: My absolute pleasure. Nothing more or less that you deserve.

Comment: `$link` wasn't defined previously either @FunkDoc. Edited to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This function is what you need :

```
function getRecords($domainId, $type, $link) {
$getRecordsQuery = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE domain_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($domainId)."' AND type='".mysql_real_escape_string($type)."'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $getRecordsQuery);
if (!$result){
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($link));
} else{
    echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>IP</td>
                <td>DynDNS</td>
                <td>TTL</td>
            </tr>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $name = $row["name"];
                $ip = $row["content"];
                $ttl = $row["ttl"];
                echo "<tr>
                    <td>". $name ."</td>
                    <td>". $ip ."</td>
                    <td>Off</td>
                    <td>". $ttl ."<td>
                </tr>";
            }
    echo "</table>";
}
}
```

Use it so :

```
getRecords(7, 'A', $link);
```

You ought to separate HTML codes from function :

```
function getRecords($domainId, $type, $link) {
$getRecordsQuery = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE domain_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($domainId)."' AND type='".mysql_real_escape_string($type)."'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $getRecordsQuery);
if (!$result){
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($link));
} else{
    return $result;
}
}
```

Use it in HTML :

```
<table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>IP</td>
            <td>DynDNS</td>
            <td>TTL</td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    $res = getRecords(7, 'A', $link);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $name = $row["name"];
            $ip = $row["content"];
            $ttl = $row["ttl"];
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$name ?></td>
                <td><?=$ip ?></td>
                <td>Off</td>
                <td><?=$ttl ?><td>
            </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
```